# O(n) algorithm for two identical points

Tags: algorithm

> The Problem Statement
>
> Given n points in a 2D plane having x and y coordinate. Two points are identical if one can be obtained from the other by multiplication by the same number. Example: (10,15) and (2,3) are identical whereas (10,15) and (10,20) are not. Suggest an O(n) algorithm which determines whether the input n points contains two identical points or not.

The simple approach can be just checking for each points i.e. if there are 5 points, for the first one I have 4 comparisons, for the second one I have 3 comparisons and so on. But that isn't an O(n) time complexity solution. I really can't think ahead of that. Any suggestions?

Comment: x1 >= x2 and y1 >= y2 and LCM of (x1, y1) should be the same as LCM of (x1, y1, x2, y2)... yeah, I think that's right.

Comment: What about point (0,0)?  Geometrically, two points are identical if the straight line that passes through both points also pass through point (0,0).  You can multiply (10,15) by the same number (zero) and obtain (0,0); but you cannot do it the other way.  Another way to look at it is to say that two points are identical if `x1 * y2 - x2 * y1 == 0`.  With this second definition, points (10,15) and (0,0) are identical.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem (your elements are rational numbers x/y).

Answer (score 4):

One obvious (but possibly inadequate) possibility would be to reduce each point to a floating point number representing the ratio, so (2,3) and (10,15) both become `0.66667`, and (10, 20) become `0.5`.

The reason this *wouldn't* work is that floating point numbers tend to be approximate, so you'd just about need to use an approximate comparison, and put up with the fact that it would show points as identical as long as they were equal to (say) 15 decimal places.

If you don't want that, you could create a rational number class that supported comparison (e.g., reduced each ratio to lowest terms).

Either way, once you've reduced a point to a single number, you just insert each into (for one possibility) a hash table. As you insert each you check whether that ratio is already in the hash table--if it is, you have an identical point. If not, insert it normally.

Comment: Your idea to use a hash table is excellent.  Just reduce the two numbers to their lowest terms (Euclid algorithm for GCD), and store a string representation like `"2/1"`.  Use `"1/0"` when denominator=0 and numerator != 0.  Case `"0/0"` depends on how you interpret the Problem definition" (see my comment in the OP).  If you decide that point (0,0) is identical to any point, you can immediately return the answer (if there is at least one other point).  The OP did not specify if coordinates can be negative; if it is the case, just keep the negative sign on the numerator.

Comment: @SciProg But we need to consider the complexity of Euclid algorithm. While it is fast, it may not satisfy OP's O(n) requirement

Comment: In the OP, `n` represents the number of points, not the size of the numbers (the bigger the numbers, the more iterations required in Euclid algorithm).  It will still be required to "reduce the numbers to their lowest terms".  Also, we have to assume that inserting and searching a hash table are O(1), otherwise the suggestion will not work (since this has to be done for each of the `n` points).

Comment: @SciProg Yes, you are right. I just want to point out that maybe we should not consider Euclid algorithm an O(1) algorithm. It will be helpful if OP can provide more information like range of input.

Comment: The problem lies mostly with the hash table.  When `n` (number of points) gets bigger, there are more collisions.  The O(1) assumption for insertion and search is no longer valid.  To be quite sure there are no collisions, you have to allocate a n*n table, which takes O(n^2) time to allocate.  I agree with your point: the OP did not specify the range of input.  If we could assume the coordinates are `m` bits integers, we could argue that there are 2^m possible values, therefore if there are more than 2^(2*m) points, by the pigeonhole principle, there must be at least two identical points.

Answer (score 2):

One way to reduce a point to a single number is to multiply the first co-ordinate of the point by product of all the second co-ordinates of the other points.

So for e.g:

```
(10, 20) -> 10 * 10 * 4 = 400 
(5, 10)  -> 5 * 20 * 4  = 400
(3, 4)   -> 3 * 20 * 10 = 600
```

The first and second point match. For large sets of points the products would be very large, and would require using a BigNumber (which will be more than O(n)) but you could keep the numbers within a reasonable limit by taking a modulo after each multiplication. Then use a hash table as suggested in Jerry Coffin's answer.

You can easily compute the product of all the second co-ordinates by doing a single forward pass then a single backwards pass over the array and keeping running products:

e.g. in Java:

```
    long m = 9223372036854775783L; // largest prime less than max long
    int[][] points = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}};
    long[] mods = new long[points.length];

    long prod = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        mods[i] = prod;
        prod = (points[i][1] * prod) % m;
    }
    prod = 1;
    for(int i = points.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        mods[i] = (mods[i] * prod) % m;
        prod = (points[i][1] * prod) % m;
    }

    HashSet<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();
    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        prod = (mods[i] * points[i][0]) % m;
        if(set.contains(prod))
            System.out.println("Found a match");
        set.add(prod);
    }
```

This algorithm assumes all the co-ordinates are integers != 0. Zeroes can be handled as special cases: all points with zero in the first place match each other, likewise for those with zero in the second place, and (0, 0) matches all points. As an optimization, the second and third pass through the array could be merged into a single pass.